# Web application doesn't run on port 80, but runs on 4200

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, server

I have an angular web app which I'm trying to deploy. When I run it on port 4200, and access the website using the external IP, I can see the web page. 
However, when I run the same application on port 80, it runs but the website isn't reachable anymore. (Connection refused)
I can see the process listening on port 80. Here's the output of netstat.

```
user@localhost:/etc$ sudo netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:80      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:22      aaa.bbb.ccc.eee:51422   ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    320 aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:22      aaa.bbb.ccc.eee:51421   ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

I have opened port 80, but it's still the same. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

try different port.. `80` may be disable or blocked from your side. Use port no. `90`.

Comment: I want to run it on 80 so that I can access it from anywhere without having to specify the port

Comment: Are you running it on iis??